# I have no idea what's wrong with my code, but my program keeps crashing

Tags: java, android

There are no syntax errors, and logically, everything seems fine to me. I've been trying to debug this code for days and I don't understand why it's crashing. I have an if/else section of code that does the majority of the work, and this is the only section that it keeps crashing in, the others work fine.

```
public void Convert(View v)
    {
        String jdate = editText1.getText().toString();
        String sdate = editText2.getText().toString();
        Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();

            //converts julian date to calendar date
            if (!jdate.isEmpty() && sdate.isEmpty())
            {
                jdate = String.format("%04d", jdate);
                int intyear = Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(jdate.charAt(0)));
                int intdayofyear = Integer.parseInt(jdate.substring(1));
                if (intdayofyear > 365) intdayofyear = 365;
                editText1.setText(intyear + intdayofyear);
                String year = Integer.toString(date.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                year = year.substring(0, 3) + Character.toString(jdate.charAt(0));
                intyear = Integer.parseInt(year);
                date.set(Calendar.YEAR, intyear);
                date.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, intdayofyear);
                editText2.setText(Calendar.MONTH + "/" + Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH + "/" + Calendar.YEAR);
                datePicker1.init(
                date.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                date.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new OnDateChangedListener(){

                    @Override
                 public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, 
                   int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {
                        editText2.setText(monthOfYear+1 + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);
                }});
            }
```

What this is supposed to be doing is taking a 4 digit number and converting it to a calendar date and displaying it on a date picker and text field.

Comment: Which line causes the crash? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Can you please post the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the actual issue is but here's a problem:

`String.format` requires an integer argument to return a `String` otherwise an `IllegalFormatConversionException` is thrown

```
jdate = String.format("%04d", jdate);
                              ^
```

`SimpleDateFormat` can be used instead for formatting dates